# How should I offset an appositive that is neither a clause nor a noun phrase?

Tags: punctuation, appositives

I'm trying to work out how to offset a tricky appositive. Here's the context:

> In Chapter 3, we consider how restrictions on *x* affect the properties of *y*.
>
> ...
>
> In Chapter 4, we consider the reverse problem *<WHAT SHOULD GO HERE?>* how restrictions on *y* result in constraints on *x*.

My gut instinct is to use an em-dash, but having done some reading around I'm no longer sure that that's correct. Any ideas?

Comment: It is chiefly a matter of style (in which you should be consistent): an em-dash, a colon, or a comma plus "i.e."

Comment: I don't follow you. Where is the appositive element that you mention in your title?

Comment: Perhaps I'm using the word incorrectly, but my understanding was that "how restrictions on *y* result in contraints on *x*" is in apposition to "the reverse problem".

Comment: You could just use "of", as in "... we consider the reverse problem of [how restrictions on y result in constraints on x]. Note that the bracketed element is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question).

Comment: I don't think it's an interrogative clause. Is the phrase "how we do it" in the sentence "This is how we do it." an interrogative clause?

Comment: Making decisions like that is what editors and printers are for. If you don't have them, follow your gut instinct, because that's what everybody else does.

Comment: Because "the reverse problem" introduces and points to "how restrictions result in," @Greybeard shows you standard choices. And BillJ offers a compact solution, too.

Comment: I'd use a comma. Something like a dash or colon is used to set something off but you want to link closely here, so comma or "of". This doesn't seem on-topic though, particularly if you don't explain your problem in more detail. Why don't you like an em-dash? What research have you done?